# Aspose Slides Table Cell Insert HTML content

Tags: c#-4.0, aspose, aspose-slides

I am working with Aspose slides to generate PPT in my application, I ran into a situation where I need to insert **HTML** text into Table Cell, I verified all blogs no one given answer to me. If any body know here please let me know. Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TextFrame's paragraph associated with each cell to insert HTML using Aspose.Slides for .NET. Check the following code:

```
//Instantiate Presentation class that represents PPTX file
using (Presentation pres = new Presentation())
{

    //Access first slide
    ISlide sld = pres.Slides[0];

   //Define columns with widths and rows with heights
   double[] dblCols = { 250, 250};
   double[] dblRows = { 150, 130, 130 };

    //Add table shape to slide
    ITable tbl = sld.Shapes.AddTable(100, 50, dblCols, dblRows);

    //Set border format for each cell
    foreach (IRow row in tbl.Rows)
        foreach (ICell cell in row)
        {
            cell.BorderTop.FillFormat.FillType = FillType.Solid;
            cell.BorderTop.FillFormat.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.Red;
            cell.BorderTop.Width = 5;

            cell.BorderBottom.FillFormat.FillType = FillType.Solid;
            cell.BorderBottom.FillFormat.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.Red;
            cell.BorderBottom.Width = 5;

            cell.BorderLeft.FillFormat.FillType = FillType.Solid;
            cell.BorderLeft.FillFormat.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.Red;
            cell.BorderLeft.Width = 5;

            cell.BorderRight.FillFormat.FillType = FillType.Solid;
            cell.BorderRight.FillFormat.SolidFillColor.Color = Color.Red;
            cell.BorderRight.Width = 5;
        }

    //Adding html text in text frame
    tbl[0, 0].TextFrame.Paragraphs.AddFromHtml(@"<html><body><p><b>This text is bold</b></p>
    <p><i>This text is italic</i></p><p>This is<sub> subscript</sub> and <sup>superscript</sup></p>
    </body></html>");

    //Write PPTX to Disk
    pres.Save("d:\\data\\table_html.pptx", Aspose.Slides.Export.SaveFormat.Pptx);
}
```

P.S. I am working as social media developer at Aspose.

Comment: Thank you for you answer it is not helped me out, in my case I am using **PresentationEx** object and **SlideEx TableEx** where I didn't get **AddFromHtml** from Paragraphs object more over Paragraphs is a collection over here, even if I choose paragrahs[0] also it is not giving AddFromHtml method.                                                                   we are using Aspose.Slides dll for .Net. I am working on this requirement since 3days till I didn't find any asnswer. More over we didn't find any proper documentation for **PresentationEx** and it's methods

Comment: Well, you are using an older version. You can download and try the latest unified version which provides both PPT and PPTX features under just Presentation class and my above code works fine with the latest version. You can download it using the following link http://goo.gl/lpKu3C